# How to restrict wordpress plugin installation just on one website (preventing multi site install)?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin which I am going to release soon. The remaining feature is to restrict the plugin usage so that people who download it can only use it JUST ON ONE WEBSITE.
I cannot seem to find any existing tutorial on how to achieve this. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to deal with this? How can I tweak the plugin code such that it can keep track of how many times the plugin has been used.
Please advise with some feasible ideas. It would be great if you can point me to some tutorials / articles that explain this concept in detail. Perhaps there might be an existing solution that was not restricted to Wordpress, but rather of a general PHP solution. Please advise me on this. Thanks !

Comment: You could use a webservice to store and fetch this, give each user a unique ID and only allow the plugin to work if it's been given an 'okay' from your own webservice. Someone could just change your code so it would work though, so it won't be very effective. Would work against 'php-noobs' though. Unless you want to spend money http://www.ioncube.com/ Or free stuff http://www.byterun.com/free-php-encoder.php

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't restrict.

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to do tha really.

## Check in WP

There are a few very dirty solutions (my opinion), like ioncubing the code and implementing a serialnumber which encodes the domain name.

## Ping your Server

You can implement a ping to your own server with the actual domain name, then you check wether this domain is allowed to use your plugin, if it is not, sue the domain owner.

## Trust your customers

But if you want more of my opinon: Trust you customers.